# Sql performance analysis after migration

Tags: sql, oracle, performance-testing, diagnostics, sql-tuning

I migrate many Oracle DBs to new virtual machines on ESX environment (exactly the same system, DB version etc). My concern is disk IO performance as there is different storage used. I need to perform sql load check before the migration and after to compare later. There is no time for more in-depth performance analysis so I decided to do very simple test:

**I execute 40 000 000 rows insert and measure the time of the operation before migration and after.**

This kind of test would be enough if the DB has no other activity, but I am not allowed to stop other connections during the test. That is why other workload can influence the results of my test inserts.

My idea to resolve this issue is to perform series of tests and gather statistics during each test so that I know what was the environment when each test was performed Then I would compare only those tests that were run in similar workload.

Could you suggest me how to approach this problem, what do you think about this idea and what statistics should I gather?

Comment: This is a question with a very wide range of possible answers. Which one is appropiate for your specific case will depend on details you don't give, so it is unlikely useful answers will be forthcomming.

Answer (score 1):

I think measuring time is not enough. Gathering statistics/factors could be done automatically by AWR.

You should start with taking Snapshots, e.g. (but set up your frequency):

```
BEGIN DBMS_WORKLOAD_REPOSITORY.modify_snapshot_settings( retention => 43200, -- Minutes (= 30 Days). Current value retained if NULL. interval => 30); -- Minutes. Current value retained if NULL. END; /
```

You can make several complex report based on Snapshots before migration and after migration. There will be any significant statistics you want.

Read more at: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/automatic-workload-repository-10g.php#snapshots